# Не работает перенаправление на главную страницу

Tags: .htaccess, apache, redirect, rewrite

Подключил модуль *rewrite* в `apache.conf`; в `htaccess` вставил вот такой вот код

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Apache установлен на Windows.

На `index.php` не перенаправляет, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для корректной работы модуля mod_rewrite ваш сервер должен поддерживать использование файлов .htaccess
Включение поддержки в конфиге apacha (по дефолту она отключена). apache2.conf

Вот, стандартное описание директивы:

```
<Directory "/usr/local/www/phpMyAdmin">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Ключевая строка здесь AllowOverride None. Для того, что ваш .htaccess заработал, меняем слово None на All. Иными словами директория приобретает следующий вид:

```
<Directory "/usr/local/www/phpMyAdmin">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

*(заметьте! имя файла .htaccess начинается с точки!)*

Comment: Попробовал, не редиректит(

Comment: @justness а какой виртуальный сервер используешь?

Comment: @justness для корректной работы модуля mod_rewrite ваш сервер должен поддерживать использование файлов .htaccess.

Comment: Я чисто скачал апач новый и установил

Comment: @justness апач какой версии?

Comment: @justness попробуй так

Comment: apache 2.4.20 VC14

Comment: @justness попробуй и отпишись

Answer (score 0):

Может, кому помогу...Провозилась день с htaccess. Меняла настройки в httpd.conf и т.д. , ничего не помогало. Оказалось, что банально файл нужно было сохранить через текстовый редактор, типа Нотпад++ (через него и сохранила). А изначально создала через обычный Блокнот

Comment: И в чём была загвоздка с блокнотом? Это тоже техтовый редактор, хоть и не удобоваримый. Может кому-то  и поможет, но не думаю, что автору данного вопроса.